# React - How to run a node_modules package at compile/build time instead of run time?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I'm using [find-up](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-up) within a custom npm package I've created to load config data from the project root into the npm package. The issue I'm having is that file-up uses the `fs` module, which only runs at compile time. When I attempt to use the npm package with a project it fails as it can't find the `fs` package.

The project is a Next.js app.

So basically, within the root **project** directory, I have a config file (let's call it `myConfig.js`).

I have installed an npm package with this project (let's call it `myPackage`).

Within `node_modules/myPackage/index.js` there is code that merges the object exported in `myConfig.js` with the default config files located in `node_modules/myPackage/defaultConfig.js`.

This new merged config file is then used by other components within `node_modules/myPackage/components/...`. I then import the components into my app. For example, I might have `import CoolComponent from "myPackage"` within `pages/index.js`.

Since the merging of the configs is done at run time and it requires the `fs` module, this fails with an error saying that the `fs` module could not be located. What I want to do is be able to run this at compile time, but I don't know how to do it.

Here's the code:

```
// node_modules/myPackage/index.js

import findUp from "find-up";
import deepMerge from "deepmerge";
import defaultConfig from "./defaultConfig";

const config = (() => {
  const path = findUp.sync("myConfig.js");
  if (path && path.length) {
    const userConfigModule = module.require(path);
    return deepMerge(defaultConfig, userConfigModule);
  }
  return defaultConfig;
})();

export default config;
```

Similarly, I would like to be able to fetch from a CMS during compile time as well, since fetching during run time would significantly slow down the initial load time and the data fetched doesn't change very often.

How do I do this?

Comment: why don't you use standard config loader library instead? reimplementing config loaders is considered bad practice unless your intention is writing a new config loader, which I don't think is the case here. 
[rc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc) or [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) will solve your needs

Comment: I'll have a look at rc. My understanding is that these won't work at run time though (like how find-up doesn't work at run time), which is why I asked about how to get them to work during compile time for a React (specifically Next.js) app

Comment: Yeah that won't work either. I can see it requires the 'fs' module so the same issue is going to occur - https://github.com/davidtheclark/cosmiconfig/blob/47d8951caf1ed5730e948d0aa0c65309eb53208f/src/readFile.ts#L1

Comment: You should not use `fs` at runtime, react is a web-based application, you won't have `fs` module in the browser. Compile time fetching is actually faster than runtime fetching. I think you are asking the wrong question, I'm assuming that your development environment is slow and you conclude that is because of config loading, which might be true or not. Hard to tell without actual metrics.

Comment: I think you may be confused about my question. I'm asking HOW to do compile time fetching. That's exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, it's really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the provided [example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-universal-configuration-build-time/next.config.js) for Next.js configuration management

In the `next.config.js`

```
import findUp from "find-up";
import deepMerge from "deepmerge";
import defaultConfig from "./defaultConfig";

const config = (() => {
  const path = findUp.sync("myConfig.js");
  if (path && path.length) {
    const userConfigModule = module.require(path);
    return deepMerge(defaultConfig, userConfigModule);
  }
  return defaultConfig;
})();

module.exports = {
    env: {
      ...config
   }
}
```

And then you can access your variables through `process.env.YOUR_VARIABLE`

Comment: next.config.js is part of the project though, not part of the npm package

Comment: Also, I need to store nested objects. process.env only lets me store strings.

Comment: @GCM Storing nested objects and storing those configs inside npm package was not part of your question. Your question was compile time config loading.

Comment: Yes it was - "Within node_modules/myPackage/index.js there is code that merges the object exported in myConfig.js with the default config files located in node_modules/myPackage/defaultConfig.js."